# using eclipse and netbeans on git

Tags: java, eclipse, git, netbeans

I am trying to work with a partner using a git repo. He uses netbeans but I use eclipse. I am having problems when I import the project into eclipse, the project has no classpath folder in eclipse so it cannot run and it is not highlighting errors in the code.

My question is is there anyway to work on the same git project with two different IDEs? And if so, how do I get eclipse to recognize the netbeans project folder to create its own .classpath.

Comment: You guys would need to agree on a common dir structure. Maybe maven can help. Then ignore the not in common files

Comment: Unless you use maven it is very hard and tedious to share Java projects across IDE's.